# How to toggle class using React Hooks as per localstorage value in App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I want to add `class="main"` to the `div` with `id="mainDiv"` only when the user is logged in and remove it when user logs out. Please someone help me.

Here is code for App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import Contentpage from './components/Contentpage/Contentpage';
import TerminalUI from './components/Terminal/Terminal';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false); //loggedout

  const user = window.localStorage.user;

  const manipulateClass = () => {
    let x = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
      x.className = 'main';
    } else {
      x.classList.remove('main');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('your window local storage :: ', user);
    if (user) {
      setStatus(true);
      manipulateClass();
      console.log('Here $tatu$ is ', status);
    } else {
      manipulateClass();
      console.log('i am log out');
    }
  },[status]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div id="mainDiv">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/chapters" component={Contentpage} />
            <Route path="/terminal" component={TerminalUI} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do it like this:

```
<div className={status && 'main'}>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you change your mindset to `State -> UI`.
Do not mutate the DOM yourself, in an imperative manner.

So, instead of

```
const user = window.localStorage.user;
```

you could have a piece of state that update every time local storage change:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

// listen for any local storage changes.
// make sure that `user` has always the latest value
useEffect(() => {
  function syncUserState() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
    setUser(user)
  }

  window.addEventListener('storage', syncUserState)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', syncUserState)
  }
}, [])
```

now that you have this, you can *derive* the other things that you need from it

```
// if `user` exist, the the class will we main, otherwise it will empty
const mainClass = user ? `main` : ``

// ...

 <div id="mainDiv" className={mainClass}>
```

From the state, you get the UI.